# Android: MapView - getMapCenter() not accurate?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I'll try to break down my problem to a simple example. I tried to draw
a circle which stays exactly in the middle of the view. For this i
used the following code in the draw method of my Overlay:

---

```
GeoPoint mapCenter = mapView.getMapCenter();
Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

int centerLat = mapCenter.getLatitudeE6();
int centerLong = mapCenter.getLongitudeE6();

Point pCircleCenter = new Point();

GeoPoint circleCenter = new GeoPoint(centerLat, centerLong);

projection.toPixels(circleCenter, pCircleCenter);

canvas.drawCircle(pCircleCenter.x, pCircleCenter.y, 30, testPaint);
```

---

When i run the code the circle is exactly in the middle of the screen.
It also stays in the mid when i scroll vertical but when i scroll
horizontal the circle moves slightly in the scrolled direction. The
circle is completely out of position after a few scrolls instead of
staying in the mid.

(This is just a simplified version of my problem but i need to get the
mid this way instead of just sticking it to the middle of the view.)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to just add an `ImageView` through the layout file.